# Having problems with spinning up Azure VMs

Tags: azure

I've been having issues spinning up Azure VMs the last couple of days.

1 core VMs in West US have been taking a while to spin up and then somehow won't let me connect via remote desktop.

Image: Windows Server 2008

Is anyone else having these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long is it taking to deploy your VM and how are you deploying it (i.e. portal, Powershell, API)?

How are you attempting to connect to the VM? Are you using the Connect button on the dashboard of the VM in the portal? Note that the RDP port is randomized for every VM by default.

Comment: I was spinning it up using the portal.  I think the problem was that our allowed ports were standard RDP and not the random ones.  I think you answered a part of the question, but the other one only Microsoft knows about.